# random.choice without duplicates in tuple in python

Tags: python, random, duplicates

I'm making a simple translation game, and I don't want duplicate "quiz" when I run this code.

Here is my current code that asks duplicate questions:

```
sentence = ("naranja", "azul", "llamada", "blanco", "negro", "cancion", "rojo", "hielo", "cara")

answer = ("orange", "blue", "call", "white", "black", "sing", "red", "ice", "face")

num = 0

while num <= len(sentence):
    quiz = random.choice(sentence)
    order = sentence.index(quiz)
    print(quiz)
    a = input("Translate in English : ")
    if a == answer[order]:
        print("Correct!")

    else :
        print("Wrong!", answer[order])
```

Comment: Consider using a list, and removing the choice element until the list is empty.

Comment: I put this code after #print("Correct!")
if quiz not in sentence :
    continue 
but this is still not working. Is anybody here to correct my code?

Comment: Just a general improvement, using a dictionary instead of 2 lists will make your code run faster since you wont need .index function everytime. You also wont need zip, and use the solution with sample. It will be easier to maintain as well when number of words increases

Answer (score 3):

The clean way to do it is to avoid manipulating indices as much as possible.

You can get pairs of (question, answer) using [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip), then use [random.shuffle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) to shuffle this list, and you just have to iterate on them:

```
from random import shuffle


sentence = ("naranja", "azul", "llamada", "blanco", "negro", "cancion", "rojo", "hielo", "cara")
answer = ("orange", "blue", "call", "white", "black", "sing", "red", "ice", "face")

associations = list(zip(sentence, answer))
shuffle(associations)

for quiz, answer in associations:
    print(quiz)
    a = input("Translate in English : ")
    if a == answer:
        print("Correct!")
    else :
        print("Wrong!", answer)
```

Comment: That is very smart! Thank you a lot!!

Comment: You're welcome! Note that if you feel that an answer has solved your problem, you may accept it (check mark on the left) and/or upvote it (once you have enough reputation)

Answer (score 1):

Try using the random `sample` function. This can be used to give you a randomized list of n elements from a given list without duplicates. Here you can take a sample with a size of the length of the questions and then iterate over the quiz questions:

```
import random

sentence = ("naranja", "azul", "llamada", "blanco", "negro", "cancion", "rojo", "hielo", "cara")

answer = ("orange", "blue", "call", "white", "black", "sing", "red", "ice", "face")

num = 0

# Get a randomly ordered list of the questions
quiz_questions = random.sample(sentence, len(sentence))

# Iterate over the random list
for quiz in quiz_questions:
    order = sentence.index(quiz)
    print(quiz)
    a = input("Translate in English : ")
    if a == answer[order]:
        print("Correct!")

    else :
        print("Wrong!", answer[order])
```